# Second level navigation drawer

Tags: usability, material-design, password

Situation: I have second level navigation drawer. 1st level is with 3 cards (LDAP configuration, LDAP encryption, LDAP authentification). On the second level(LDAP configuration) there are no cards, only plain input fields.

Problem: I have 2 bottom fields - username and password. When a username is changed, password field becomes required. If I make this field required, everytime user presses on "Change LDAP configuration" only to see what was set, he is required to enter a password again, and again, and again... This is just because REST API doesn't return the password and I can't store it (see image below, for the password I use placeholder as "*******".

Question: Any ideas how to change this UI, to simplify user experience (if the username was not changed, allow to save settings and IF username was changed, require a new password).

[image: UI example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following:

- you don't show the *password* field at all
- you may inform the user that they will be asked for password later
- when the username is changed, the user receives another dialog requesting them to enter the password, and this is the moment you store the password

or (if possible)

- you make the *password* field "required" only after the username is changed